# Python pandas: how to fast process the value in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi there is a dataframe like the following dataframes df1. The data type is string.

```
    eye         nose       mouse       ear
  34_35_a      45_66_b    45_64_a     78_87_a
  35_38_a      75_76_b    95_37_a     38_79_a
  64_43_a      85_66_b    65_45_a     87_45_a
```

I want to get the dataframe like the following dataframe. The eye data is divided into eye_x, eye_y, the other columns is the same, the data type is float.

```
 eye_x   eye_y    nose_x   nose_y     mouse_x  mouse_y     ear_x   ear_y        
    34       35       45       66         45        64        78       87
    35       38       75       76         95        37        38       79
    64       43       85       66         65        45        87       45
```

Until now I know how to get the (x, y) value together  with the following code:

```
 eye           nose       mouse       ear
  (34, 35)      (45,66)    (45,64)     (78,87)
  (35, 38)      (75,76)    (95,37)     (38,79)
  (64, 43)      (85,66)    (65,45)     (87,45)
```

```
def process_xy(val_str):
    s = val_str.split('_')
    x = float(s[0])
    y = float(s[1])
    label = int(s[2])
    return np.array([x, y])

keypoint_cols = list(df.columns)
d = None
for col in keypoint_cols:
    df[col+'_xy'] = df[col].apply(process_xy)

df2 = df.drop(keypoint_cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: You have 3 decent solutions here. Is there something wrong with them?

Comment: Thanks, all answer is good. I am  just wondering which answer I will accept it. I am waiting for the votes.

Comment: If it is a dilemma, I have two suggestions: 1. Time all solutions on data and pick the fastest, or 2. if 1 doesn't work, flip a coin ;)

Comment: thanks I will do it. Actually I am using your code to do it. But I will try to use others' code to compare it . Please give me some time, I want to be fair to every one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `stack`ing and `unstack`ing again.

```
v = df.stack().str.split('_', expand=True).iloc[:, :-1]
v.columns = ['x', 'y']

v = v.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
v.columns = v.columns.map('_'.join)
```

```
v.sort_index(axis=1)

  ear_x ear_y eye_x eye_y mouse_x mouse_y nose_x nose_y
0    78    87    34    35      45      64     45     66
1    38    79    35    38      95      37     75     76
2    87    45    64    43      65      45     85     66
```

Answer (score 2):

What I will do `str.split`, with `stack` and `apply(pd.Series)`

```
s=df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_')).stack().apply(pd.Series)# convert to list then unnesting it 
s=s.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').dropna(1).rename(columns={0:'x',1:'y'}).unstack() # apply the numeric check , drop the na
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)# change multiple column to flatten 
s
Out[1274]: 
   eye_x  nose_x  mouse_x  ear_x  eye_y  nose_y  mouse_y  ear_y
0     34      45       45     78     35      66       64     87
1     35      75       95     38     38      76       37     79
2     64      85       65     87     43      66       45     45
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a list comprehension and `pd.concat`.

```
res = pd.concat([df[col].str.split('_', expand=True).iloc[:, :2].add_prefix(col) \
                for col in df], axis=1).astype(int)
```

I leave the column suffix renaming as an exercise.

**Result**

```
  eye0 eye1 nose0 nose1 mouse0 mouse1 ear0 ear1
0   34   35    45    66     45     64   78   87
1   35   38    75    76     95     37   38   79
2   64   43    85    66     65     45   87   45
```

**Explanation**

- Aggregate each category along columns using `pd.concat` with `axis=1`.
- Split values by `_`, use `expand=True` and take only first 2 components.
- Convert to `int` using `pd.DataFrame.astype`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([dict(zip([i + '_x',i + '_y'], y.split('_')[:2])) for y in x]) 
                               for i, x in df.items()], axis=1).astype(int)
print (df1)
   eye_x  eye_y  nose_x  nose_y  mouse_x  mouse_y  ear_x  ear_y
0     34     35      45      66       45       64     78     87
1     35     38      75      76       95       37     38     79
2     64     43      85      66       65       45     87     45
```